# How to set current time on Linux?

Tags: linux, date

Why is the output of the following commands different?

```
root@vmi2115:/var# hwclock
Sun 26 Jun 2011 01:21:38 PM CEST  -0.273230 seconds
root@vmi2495:/var# date
Sun Jun 26 15:21:39 CEST 2011
root@vmi2115:/var#
```

And can I change the current time on Linux?

Comment: A quick search of Google returns this link: > http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/

Answer (score 97):

Usually you'll want to have the time set automatically, and in that case, you'll want to set up `ntpd` to automatically set the time for you.

The specifics differ slightly from distribution to distribution, but if you're running Ubuntu,  for instance, there's a guide on [setting up NTP on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime). Otherwise, just Google `ntpd <distribution-name>`, and you'll probably find it.

If you want to set it manually, however, you can use `date --set="<date string>"`. Examples of this could be:

```
date --set="23 June 1988 10:00:00"
date --set="10:00:00"
```

Answer (score 41):

Set the Hardware Clock to the current System Time.

```
# hwclock --systohc
```

Set the System Time from the Hardware Clock.

```
# hwclock --hctosys
```

Answer (score 27):

Just `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` and everything will be fine.

There is more information regarding this on [Ubuntu Official Documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp).

Comment: please elaborate further on your answer and supply an explanation to the QA and future readers what does the command you mentioned do and why you recommend such action. note: the QA asked how to change the time, not how to keep it synced.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn ok

Comment: This still has no explanation. What should I expect to happen if I run this command?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/NTP.html

Comment: Worked great for setting exact time.

Comment: Great answer with link to the official documentation, why do people still fuss about it asking for "Further explanation"

Comment: @xelber the link in the answer doesn't work anymore (redirects to entire doc). that is why people fuss about "further explanation".

Answer (score 13):

Another common, very annoying problem is, when the wrong timezone is selected...

Check the timezone with the date output:

> $ date
>
> Fre Aug 23 18:47:04 UTC 2013

To correct the timezone type:

> $ sudo tzselect

and select the correct Region with the corresponding numbers.

A second task is to set the correct time:

> $ sudo date --set="18:37:00"

Or simply take the time from the HW-Clock:

> $ sudo hwclock --hctosys

Answer (score 5):

"hwclock" is date of hardware (machine), and "date" is date of software (operative system).

For change pc hardware date:

```
hwclock --set --date="2013-7-31 09:30"
```

For change software date:

```
date --set "2013-7-31 09:30"
```

Answer (score 4):

In `CentOS` timezones are located in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`, to change the system date to a **specific timezone** you can:

First, make a backup of the existing localtime file.

```
sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
```

Next, create the link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Lisbon  /etc/localtime
```

Check the new system date by typing `date`.

To adjust the Linux system **date manually** you can type:

```
date -s "11 MAR 2006 11:11:11"
```

OR

```
date --set="11 MAR 2015 11:11:11"
```

OR

```
date +%Y%m%d -s "20150311"
```

To set the **Hardware Clock** to the current System Time:

```
hwclock --systohc
```

OR

```
hwclock -w
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
date +%T -s "12:21:00"
```

or

```
date +%T%p -s "12:22:20AM"
date +%T%p -s "12:23:30PM"
```

Answer (score 1):

> can I change the current time on Linux?

For me, I needed to run this command first:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
```

Otherwise, systemd would reset the time immediately. After stopping the systemd service, running `date` works as expected:

```
$ sudo date -s 'january 1 1971'
Fri Jan  1 00:00:00 CET 1971
$ date
Fri Jan  1 00:00:00 CET 1971
```

While the service was running, the `date -s` command seemed to work, but running `date` a moment later would give me the systemd time again.

Answer (score 0):

`date` return the time given as the time from the moment the cpu started plus the internal hardware clock given time, `hwclock` gives the time the internal clock has.

The cpu based time tend to drift the long the machine is up, that is the reason behind the existence of `hwclock --hctosys` command. Also is one of the reasons behind the the use of the Network Protocol Time, which is used to coordinate time internationally on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

use this if haven't NTP client

```
date -s $(wget -q -O - http://www.timeapi.org/eest/now | cut -d '+' -f 1 | tr -d : | tr -d - | tr -d T | cut -c 1-12)
```

**eest** in URL is your local timezone

You can use **utc** ... and etc

Comment: but this one working for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/683136

Answer (score 0):

From [Sebastian's answer](https://superuser.com/a/302431/902063) and [Ubuntu OS guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime):

Using the command line (Terminal), you can use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`:

1. Open a terminal window by going to Applications>Accessories>Terminal
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`
3. Follow the directions in the terminal.

The timezone info is saved in `/etc/timezone` - which can be edited.

My environment OS: Mendel Linux, HW: Google Coral